# How to play blob audio in html audio player using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, blob, audio-recording, audio-player

I am saving blob audio in the mysql database as a blob. the format of the audio file is like this

```
blob:abc.com/4b67d486-61e9-4db7-afbe-b693a34ea758
```

Its saving in the database blob format like this

[image]

And when I fetch it using php its show in html like this

```
<audio src="blob:abc.com/4b67d486-61e9-4db7-afbe-b693a34ea758" controls="" id="audio-playback" class=""></audio>
```

But the problem is audio is not playing when I try to play it

I am missing something can anybody help how to play blob audio using php

Comment: Is `blob:abc.com/` example or literal? I get the domain part being sample, and if so we recommend `example.com` to be explicit. And is `blob:` supposed to be like a data URI? The value appears to be a UUID, not an audio stream. Are you supposed to be load a file from disk or elsewhere?

Comment: i add option to record audio and it is going as blob in database in above format

Comment: I’m not sure what that statement means. 74 bytes, per the screenshot, is probably not a very audio file. I think there’s something else you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you encode the blob?

This can work:

```
$audio_data = base64_encode($blob);

echo '<audio src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,'.$audio_data.'" controls="controls" id="audio-playback" class=""></audio>';
```

### EDIT: Wav Format

If the audio file is in WAV format, you need to make sure that the audio tag in the HTML is also specified to be of the same type with `type="audio/wav"`:

```
<audio src="blob:abc.com/4b67d486-61e9-4db7-afbe-b693a34ea758" type="audio/wav" controls="" id="audio-playback" class=""></audio>
```

Also, make sure that the server from which the audio is being served from is able to serve WAV files.

Comment: yes I try it too and its in wav format

Comment: You need to specify the file type. Check updated answer.

Comment: not working when I try to open the url from audio file its show I donot have permission to open it